# XCode - String before array in .detailtextlabel

Tags: objective-c, xcode

im assuming this is possible but cant seem to work it out... I have:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = person.age;
```

in the table view it displays just the age, i want it to display as:

```
age: 22
```

rather than just

```
22
```

cheers for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Objective-C:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"age: %i",person.age];
```

the **format specifier** `%i` is for ints, I don't know the **type** of `person.age`. If it is a `NSNumber`, `NSString` or any other subclass of `NSObject` you have to use `%@`.

---

Just so you know it for the future, in Swift you would make:

#### Swift:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = "age: \(person.age)"
```

Much easier right ;-).

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that. For example:

```
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [@"age: " stringByAppendingString:person.age];
```

or

```
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"age: %@", person.age];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this is age property is integer type:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Age: %d", person.age];
```

if it a NSString type use %@ instead of %d.

Comment: person.age is a NSString, he is assigning it to a .text property

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"age: %@", person.age];
```

Comment: person.age is a NSString, he is assigning it to a .text property, use %@ instead of %d

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski you are right, i miss_understood